# GeoServer s3 uri with ImagePyramid plugin

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, image-pyramids, amazon-s3, s3

I would like to create pyramid and use the ImagePyramid plugin to create a store in GeoServer. I know GeoServer has a [community module](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/community/s3-geotiff/index.html) to support S3 uri in GeoTiff file, is it possible to use the S3 url also in the setup of ImagePyramid store?

Comment: did you try it? did it work?

Comment: i'm building the test environment from draft and i would like to understand if it is possible or if I have to consider other approaches to manage pyramid (or to support s3 using for example s3fs but I read it's not the best solution)

Answer (score 1):

I tried to configure both ImagePyramid plugin and S3GeoTiff community module and I found it isn't supported the s3 uri provided by community module also in the pyramid plugin :(